# How to use Delphi "in" operator in C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, set, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I'm a newbie programmer. I need to use Delphi's `in` operator in C++ Builder XE like this:

```c
if (dgColLines in DBGrid->Options)
    // include vertical lines in total (one per column)
    TotalColumnWidth = TotalColumnWidth + ColumnCount;
```

```c
if (dgColLines **in** DBGrid->Options)
```

How to do that in C++ Builder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps [Language Support for the VCL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Language_Support_for_the_VCL_%28C%2B%2B%29) in the C++ Builder documentation will help find equivalents.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`Contains`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Set.Contains) method to check if a set contains a specific element:

```
if( DBGrid->Options.Contains(dgColLines) )
  TotalColumnWidth = TotalColumnWidth + ColumnCount;
```

Answer (score 9):

Looking the the property in question, `TDBGrid.Options`, its type is [`TDBGridOptions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGridOptions) which is defined as:

```
typedef System::Set<TDBGridOption, TDBGridOption::dgEditing,
    TDBGridOption::dgTitleHotTrack> TDBGridOptions;
```

As you can see, C++ Builder uses the template [`System::Set<T, minEl, maxEl>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Set) to emulate Delphi set types.

All of the functionality available using the built in Delphi set operators is exposed through the [methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Set_Methods) of `Set`. Specifically to this question, set membership is testing using [`Contains()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Set.Contains).